# ipe-7.1.4 pdflatex conversion error

Tags: pdftex, ipe

I am trying to write A (so as to label a point in my figure) in ipe-7.1.4. Apparently, it is done through the following .tex file which I have managed to find in the conversion directory. Note the location of the A and the symbol % following it in the .tex file. The problem is that the pdf file it is producing is empty. I have no idea how to fix this. Can anyone please help? Thanks in advance.

```
\pdfcompresslevel0
\nonstopmode
\expandafter\ifx\csname pdfobjcompresslevel\endcsname\relax\else\pdfobjcompresslevel0\fi
\ifnum\the\pdftexversion<140\errmessage{Pdftex is too old. Set IPEANCIENTPDFTEX environment variable!}\fi
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\PageTitle}[1]{#1}
\newdimen\ipefs
\newcommand{\ipesymbol}[4]{\ipefs 1ex\pdfliteral{(#1) (\the\ipefs) (#2) (#3) (#4) sym}}
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{red}{rgb}{1,0,0}
\definecolor{green}{rgb}{0,1,0}
\definecolor{blue}{rgb}{0,0,1}
\definecolor{yellow}{rgb}{1,1,0}
\definecolor{orange}{rgb}{1,0.647,0}
\definecolor{gold}{rgb}{1,0.843,0}
\definecolor{purple}{rgb}{0.627,0.125,0.941}
\definecolor{gray}{gray}{0.745}
\definecolor{brown}{rgb}{0.647,0.165,0.165}
\definecolor{navy}{rgb}{0,0,0.502}
\definecolor{pink}{rgb}{1,0.753,0.796}
\definecolor{seagreen}{rgb}{0.18,0.545,0.341}
\definecolor{turquoise}{rgb}{0.251,0.878,0.816}
\definecolor{violet}{rgb}{0.933,0.51,0.933}
\definecolor{darkblue}{rgb}{0,0,0.545}
\definecolor{darkcyan}{rgb}{0,0.545,0.545}
\definecolor{darkgray}{gray}{0.663}
\definecolor{darkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.392,0}
\definecolor{darkmagenta}{rgb}{0.545,0,0.545}
\definecolor{darkorange}{rgb}{1,0.549,0}
\definecolor{darkred}{rgb}{0.545,0,0}
\definecolor{lightblue}{rgb}{0.678,0.847,0.902}
\definecolor{lightcyan}{rgb}{0.878,1,1}
\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.827}
\definecolor{lightgreen}{rgb}{0.565,0.933,0.565}
\definecolor{lightyellow}{rgb}{1,1,0.878}
\definecolor{black}{gray}{0}
\definecolor{white}{gray}{1}
\def\ipesetcolor{\pdfcolorstack0 push{0 0 0 0 k 0 0 0 0 K}}
\def\iperesetcolor{\pdfcolorstack0 pop}




\pagestyle{empty}
\newcount\bigpoint\dimen0=0.01bp\bigpoint=\dimen0
\begin{document}
\begin{picture}(500,500)
\setbox0=\hbox{\normalsize
\ipesetcolor
A%
\iperesetcolor}
\count0=\dp0\divide\count0 by \bigpoint
\pdfxform attr{/IpeId /004e4300 /IpeStretch 1 /IpeDepth \the\count0}0\put(0,0){\pdfrefxform\pdflastxform}
\end{picture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with `A%`. Before that line you have `ipesetcolor` which seems to set a white color for your letter `A`.

Answer (score 6):

The problem has nothing to do with `A%`.

Before that line you have `\ipesetcolor` which sets a white color for your letter `A`.

Removing `\ipesetcolor` before and `\iperesetcolor` after that line lets you have the desired result.